# linux add bleed to pdf that is the average colour of the page

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

because of inexperience with professional printing, we did not take bleed margin into account when creating a small magazine. A lot of pages have text cut off because of this. We can reprint them, but to get it right, we would have to make bleed margins for each page specifically, because they all have different designs and colours. Is it possible to add bleed margins (5mm) to all pages, where the colour of the margins is equal to the average colour of the page? It would be even better if it extended the colour of the last pixel of the edge, but that is probably too much to ask, isn't it.

Comment: A truly 'professional' printer would have told you about this before they ran the job. It would be obvious to them, even if you didn't know beforehand. I'd take it to a different shop & ask their guidance.

Comment: Are you asking how to add white margins to the page ? This is normally done by setting the page-size and adding the `-dFIXEDMEDIA` switch ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446552/resizing-a-pdf-using-ghostscript)). For standard bleed sizes see [this article](https://www.bindersinc.com/resources/what-is-bleed-printing), but you should ask your printer.

Comment: I agree that they should've told me about it beforehand, but now we don't have much time nor money to go to another printshop. They have offered us a free reprint.

I am not asking about white margins, but about coloured margins that match the average colour of each page. I already asked about if white margins were okay, but they will show quite clearly after cutting.

Comment: One solution seems to add pictures or other colored objects that are too large for the printed page, which will look well after the paper is cut. But I can't help with the automatic color choice. Or you could make the page size too big with no margins.

Comment: You would first have to determine the 'average colour of the page'. To do that you could use the inkcov device which would tell you how much of each ink is used on the page. Effectively that's the average colour. Then you need to set the media size you want, and set -dFIXEDMEDIA so that it can't be changed. I think you would also need to change the PageSize Policy to 5 (select nearest and do not scale). Finally you would need to set a BeginPage procedure to fill the page with the selected colour. Its all possible, but non-trivial.

Comment: Oh and you'd need to use a pdfmark to add a BleedBox to the output PDF file.

Comment: Do you have enough "real" margin that you could just scale all the pages up slightly to make a larger page size? That would be one way - the colour would come automatically. You could then set a bleed box. For example, `cpdf in.pdf -scale-to-fit "x y" AND -bleedbox "5mm 5mm w h" -o out.pdf` for suitable values of x, y, w and h.